# Loop cut/subdivide triangle

Tags: mesh

I have the top shape. If I subdivide it, I get the second shape. What I want is a way to get the third. I made it by subdividing the two long edges of the triangle, and then knifing between them, but I want a way to automate it.[image]

Comment: In edge select mode, select the 3 edges starting from the vertex on the right, then W subdivide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possibilities (at least).

- <kbd>W</kbd> then subdivide, once the edges are selected: you have to be in edge select mode to do that.

[image]

- Knife tool (activated by <kbd>K</kbd>) then hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to cut at the middle of the wanted parts (you have to click at each cut you want to position and to validate with <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end)

[image]

This last way is certainly more easy. For instance :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In edit mode, select the left hand edges and press Offset Edge Slide in the toolbar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>).  A factor of 0.5 will place the new edge in the centre.

[image]